# I want to get the project balance after project amount is subtract to project cost. using decimal c#

Tags: c#

First Process is to get value on database and search the Project Amount. after dislplaying it in amount.Text here is the code in search button

```
private void ButSearchGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox6.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Please Input Control #..");
              
                clear2();
            }

            else
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_expense WHERE Contract_ID Like'%' +@Contract_ID+ '%'", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Contract_ID", textBox6.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                datagridview.DataSource = dt;
                this.datagridview.Columns["id"].Visible = false;


                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_expense where contract_id=@contract_id ", conn);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("contract_id", textBox6.Text);
                SqlDataReader rdr;
                rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();



                if (rdr.Read())
                {

                    lblid.Text = rdr["CONTRACT_ID"].ToString();
                    lblcontractor.Text = rdr["CONTRACTOR"].ToString();
                    lblstatus.Text = rdr["PROJECT_STATUS"].ToString();
                    lblstart.Text = rdr["COVERED_PERIOD"].ToString();
                    lblend.Text = rdr["END_PERIOD"].ToString();
                    amount.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["PROJECT_AMOUNT"]).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PH"));    // here is the code to get decimal amount in database and throw to amount.Text it will display ex. ₱48,000,000.00
                    lblcons.Text = rdr["CONTRACT"].ToString();
                    label32.Text = rdr["id"].ToString();
                    projectid.Text = rdr["projectid"].ToString();
                    

                }


                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Data Exist");
                    clear2();
                }



                conn.Close();
                refresh();
            }
        }
```

now the next step is to sum the project costs amount in the database i created a button to trigger function to sum all the project cost and display it to lblcost.Text. here is the code below

```
private void butGenerateExpense(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                decimal sum;
                decimal subTotal = 0;
                decimal subTotal1 = 0;
                
    
                if (this.datagridview.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
    
                       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.datagridview.Rows)
                        {
                            if (row.Cells[7].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                subTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[7].Value);
                            }
                        }
    
                        this.lbl1.Text = subTotal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PH"));
                        
                }
               
    
                if (this.datagridview.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
    
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.datagridview.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[12].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[12].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            subTotal1 += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[12].Value);
                        }
                    }
    
                    this.lbl2.Text = subTotal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PH"));
                }
    
              
                sum = subTotal + subTotal1;
                textTotal.Text = sum.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PH"));
```

Now it will display the total project cost in lblcost.Text after click the button to generate the expense.

here is my concern i want to Subtract the project Amount and project Cost and display the project Balance in the lblbalance.Text  i want the the value and convert into decimal but i got this error and logic since it was being get search first in a process.

my first Code attempt is this.

```
private void butGenerateExpense(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
decimal a, b, diff;
a = Convert.ToDecimal(amount.Text);
b = Convert.ToDecimal(textTotal.Text);

diff = a - b;

lblbalance.Text = diff.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PH"));
```

after pressing the button generate expense together with the codes to get the project cost.

The Error: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: too much code to read..

Comment: hi Lei Yang. my problem is # 3 tab. The error says cannot convert string to decimal.

Comment: Could be something simple like changing the decimal separator "," to "." or vice versa, depends on your used culture.

Comment: sorry for the confuse the error is actually say : System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: I would highly recommend reducing your problem to a minimal reproducible example. If I understand the issue correctly that should be really easy to do, and show the actual issue much better than a huge realm of code, where most of it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the numbers to text using a specific culture, you need to use the same culture when parsing the text. See the [TryParse overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-decimal-tryparse(system-string-system-globalization-numberstyles-system-iformatprovider-system-decimal@)) that takes a IFormatProvider, i.e. a cultureInfo.

```
decimal.TryParse(textTotal.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PH"), out var result);
```

If you are converting strings to numbers for anything other than input or deserializing, or the other way around, you are doing something wrong. Try to keep the numbers as decimal values as long as possible. A common approach is to use a property with a backing field, with a setter that also updates the corresponding text-box.